# Infinite Hausdorff space that is not homeomorphic to any proper quotient

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $S$ be a set and $\vartheta$ be an equivalence relation on $S$. We say that $\vartheta$ is *proper* if there are $x\neq y\in S$ with $(x,y)\in\vartheta$.

Is there an infinite Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ such that for every proper equivalence relation $\vartheta$ on $X$ we have $X\not\cong X/\vartheta$?

Comment: A strongly rigid infinite Hausdorff space would do, right?

Comment: Oh, possibly, have to think about it. Please post your example as an answer

Comment: Well, you know more about strongly rigid spaces then I do. Doe strongly rigid infinite Hausdorff spaces exist? If so, let $X$ be one. If $f \colon X/\vartheta \to X$ is a homeomorphism, compose it with the quotient map $q \colon X \to X/\vartheta$, to obtain a continuous map $(f \circ q) \colon X \to X$. Since $X$ is strongly rigid, the composition is constant or the identity. Consequently $\vartheta$ is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a strongly rigid infinite Hausdorff space. Let $\vartheta$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. Let $q \colon X \to X/\vartheta$ be the quotient map. If there is a homeomorphism $f \colon X/\vartheta \to X$, then $(f \circ q)$ is a continuous map from $X$ to itself; hence constant or the identity. Since $X$ is infinite, we deduce that $\vartheta$ is trivial.